# Angular checkbox only select one values data when I wanted multiple values

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hi folks I am currently working on a `angular tickbox` which I want to tick multiple values.But for mine when I click English box  it displays all data regarding English but when I tick another checkbox it only displays value of the latest box German but not english & german together. How do I populate both tick boxes data on the home page graph.

**Ts code**

```
public onChangeLearnPrograms(event: any): void {
    if (event.source.selected) {
      this.homePageFilter.learn_Programs= event.source.value;
      this.generateCharts();
    }
  }
```

**html code**

```
    <mat-form-field class="lg-filter-input-width">
      <mat-select placeholder = "learningprograms" formControlName="learn_Programs"multiple> 
        <mat-option type="checkbox" (onSelectionChange)="onChangeLearnPrograms($event)"
        *ngFor="let control of LearnPrograms | fieldFilter : 'learn_Programs' : filterFormGroup.value.learn_Programs" 
        [value]="control.learn_Programs" > {{control.learn_Programs}} </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
</mat-panel-description>
```

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox emits that it was selected but does not know about any other selected checkboxes. Therefore you currently overwrite the first value when a new checkbox is selected.

You should either have `learn_Programs` be an array and remove/add once an event triggers `onChangeLearnPrograms` or whenever the function is called, iterate over the checkboxes to get which ones are selected.

Comment: can you please  show me an example bro if you dont mind?

Comment: Initialize learn_Programs as an array and change `this.homePageFilter.learn_Programs= event.source.value;` to `this.homePageFilter.learn_Programs.push(event.source.value);`

Comment: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)  getting this error when i did  this.homePageFilter.learn_programs.push(event.source.value);

Comment: You need to initialize `learn_programs` as an array instead of string. I am not able to help you with more details unless more information is provided about the class you implemented.